# Why is `self` in Python objects immutable?

Tags: python, object

Why can't I perform an action like the following:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self = 5

t = Test()
print t
```

I would expect it to print `5` since we're overwriting the instance with it, but instead it doesn't do anything at all. Doesn't even throw an error. Just ignores the assignment.

I understand that there would be hardly any situations where one would want to do that, but it still seems odd that you can't.

**Update:** I now understand *why* it doesn't work, but I'd still like to know if there is any way of replacing an instance from within the instance.

Comment: "From within", not really: __new__, which I suggested, belongs to the class, not to the instance. You can normally alter the __class__ and/or the state (via __dict__) of most objects ("most" because some are immutable and/or don't use __dict__), but not the *IDENTITY* of the object -- id(obj) will be the same before and after your alteration. Telemachus' Ship comes to mind, but this other subject seems more appropriate for a different question, as it has little to do with the title of this one.

Comment: -1: Replacing an instance breaks a fundamental concept: objects have unique identity.  Returning a new instance -- that is -- a Factory -- makes some sense.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

*Any* simple assignment to *any* argument of *any* function behaves exactly the same way in Python: binds that name to a different value, and does nothing else whatsoever. "No special case is special enough to break the rules", as the Zen of Python says!-)

So, far from it being odd (that simply=assigning to a specific argument in a specific function has no externally visible effect whatsoever), it would be utterly *astonishing* if this specific case worked in any other way, just because of the names of the function and argument in question.

Should you ever want to make a class that constructs an object of a different type than itself, such behavior is of course quite possible -- but it's obtained by overriding the special method `__new__`, **not** `__init__`:

```
class Test(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        return 5

t = Test()
print t
```

This *does* emit `5`.  The `__new__` / `__init__` behavior in Python is an example of the "two-step construction" design pattern: the "constructor" proper is `__new__` (it builds and returns a (normally uninitialized) object (normally a new one of the type/class in question); `__init__` is the "initializer" which properly initializes the new object.

This allows, for example, the construction of objects that are immutable once constructed: in this case everything must be done in `__new__`, before the immutable object is constructed, since, given that the object is immutable, `__init__` cannot mutate it in order to initialize it.

Answer (score 10):

It doesnt "ignore" the assignment. The assignment works just fine, you created a local name that points to the data 5.

If you *really* want to do what you are doing...

```
class Test(object):
    def __new__(*args):
        return 5
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran a quick test, and you can assign to `self`.  Inside your `__init__()` method, print out the value of `self`.  You'll see that it's 5.

What you're missing here is that parameters are passed by value in Python.  So, changing the value of a variable in a function or method won't change it for the outside world.

All that being said, I would strongly advise against ever changing `self`.

Answer (score 1):

Dr. Egon Spengler: It would be bad.
Dr. Peter Venkman: I'm fuzzy on the whole good/bad thing. What do you mean, "bad"?
Dr. Egon Spengler: Try to imagine all life as you know it stopping instantaneously and every molecule in your body exploding at the speed of light.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to do this, though not with immutable types like `int`:

```
>>> class Test(list):
    ... def __init__(self):
    ...    list.__init__(self, [1,2,3])   # self = [1,2,3] seems right, but isn't

>> t = Test()
>> print t
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self = 5

t = Test()
print t
```

is like having this PHP (only other lang i know, sorry)

```
class Test {
    function __construct() {
            $this = 5;
        }
}
```

I don't see how it makes sense. replacing the instance with a value?

Comment: How does it not make sense? It would be the same as doing: 

$test = new Test(); 
$test = 5;

But from within instead of outside.