# Python object cache

Tags: python, caching, python-2.7, python-2.x

I tried a bit of code but it seems to cause issues:

```
class Page:
    cache = []


    """ Return cached object """
    def __getCache(self, title):
        for o in Page.cache:
            if o.__searchTerm == title or o.title == title:
                return o
        return None


    """ Initilize the class and start processing """
    def __init__(self, title, api=None):
        o = self.__getCache(title)
        if o:
            self = o
            return
        Page.cache.append(self)

        # Other init code
        self.__searchTerm = title
        self.title = self.someFunction(title)
```

Then I try:

```
a = Page('test')
b = Page('test')

print a.title # works
print b.title # AttributeError: Page instance has no attribute 'title'
```

Whats wrong with this bit of code? Why wont it work? Is there a way to make it work? If not how do I go about easily and transparently to the end user caching objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want to manipulate the creation, you need to change `__new__`.

```
>>> class Page(object):
...     cache = []
...     """ Return cached object """
...     @classmethod
...     def __getCache(cls, title):
...         for o in Page.cache:
...             if o.__searchTerm == title or o.title == title:
...                 return o
...         return None
...     """ Initilize the class and start processing """
...     def __new__(cls, title, api=None):
...         o = cls.__getCache(title)
...         if o:
...             return o
...         page = super(Page, cls).__new__(cls)
...         cls.cache.append(page)
...         page.title = title
...         page.api = api
...         page.__searchTerm = title
...         # ...etc
...         return page
... 
>>> a = Page('test')
>>> b = Page('test')
>>> 
>>> print a.title # works
test
>>> print b.title
test
>>> 
>>> assert a is b
>>>
```

**EDIT:** using `__init__`:

```
>>> class Page(object):
...     cache = []
...     @classmethod
...     def __getCache(cls, title):
...         """ Return cached object """
...         for o in Page.cache:
...             if o.__searchTerm == title or o.title == title:
...                 return o
...         return None
...     def __new__(cls, title, *args, **kwargs):
...         """ Initilize the class and start processing """
...         existing = cls.__getCache(title)
...         if existing:
...             return existing
...         page = super(Page, cls).__new__(cls)
...         return page
...     def __init__(self, title, api=None):
...         if self in self.cache:
...             return
...         self.cache.append(self)
...         self.title = title
...         self.api = api
...         self.__searchTerm = title
...         # ...etc
... 
>>> 
>>> a = Page('test')
>>> b = Page('test')
>>> 
>>> print a.title # works
test
>>> print b.title
test
>>> assert a is b
>>> assert a.cache is Page.cache
>>>
```

Comment: @BrendanLong, you can use `__init__` if you like if you have a way to find out when to skip it.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot really change the instance of a created object once it has been created. When setting `self` to something else, all you do is change the reference that variable points to, so the actual object is not affected.

This also explains why the `title` attribute is not there. You return as soon as you change the local `self` variable, preventing the current instance to get the `title` attribute initialized (not to mention that `self` at that point wouldn’t point to the right instance).

So basically, you cannot change the object during its initialization (in `__init__`) as at that point it has already been created, and assigned to the variable. A constructor call like `a = Page('test')` is actually the same as:

```
a = Page.__new__('test')
a.__init__('test')
```

So as you can see, the `__new__` class constructor is called first, and that’s actually who’s responsible for creating the instance. So you could overwrite the class’ `__new__` method to manipulate the object creation.

A generally preferred way however is to create a simple factory method, like this:

```
@classmethod
def create (cls, title, api = None):
    o = cls.__getCache(title)
    if o:
        return o
    return cls(title, api)
```

Answer (score 1):

`self` is a normal local variable, so setting `self = ..` just changes what the `self` variable points to *in that function*. It doesn't change the actual object.

See: [Is it safe to replace a self object by another object of the same type in a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216356/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-self-object-by-another-object-of-the-same-type-in-a-meth)

To do what you want, you could use a static function as a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29):

```
class Page:
    cache = []


    """ Return cached object """
    @staticmethod
    def create(title):
        for o in Page.cache:
            if o.__searchTerm == title or o.title == title:
                return o
        return Page(title)

    """ Initilize the class and start processing """
    def __init__(self, title, api=None):
        Page.cache.append(self)

        # Other init code
        self.__searchTerm = title
        self.title = title


a = Page.create('test')
b = Page.create('test')

print a.title
print b.title
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work? If not how do I go about easily and transparently to the end user caching objects?

Comment: Rather than setting self, tried `return o` but then I get yelled at by python that __init__ should return None

Comment: @Justin808 Apparently not. I was looking at using `__new__`, but apparently that won't work (see poke's answer).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to go with a factory. I was hoping I could be transparent to the user, but doesn't look like python will allow that.

Comment: Is there any way to make `__init__` private so `o = Page('test')` called by the user would fail?

Comment: @Justin808 See the new answer. They get around how `__init__()` always gets called by just not having one. I wish I had looked into it more.