# Is there a way to detect when a python program is going to end?

Tags: python, callback, python-2.7, python-2.x

Is there a way to detect when a python program is going to end? Something like a callback I can connect to?

I have a class thats keeping a [cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054250/python-object-cache) and I'd like to write the cache out to disk before the program ends. If I can do that then I can load it up from disk the first time its used and have a persistent cache.

I'm looking for a callback type thing though cause I want to automate it so the user doesn't have to do anything to have the cache saved.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be a halting problem joke.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`atexit.register(some_function)`](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html#atexit.register) or simply decorate your function with `@atexit.register`. It will be called when the interpreter terminates.

Example:

```
import atexit
@atexit.register
def save_cache():
    print 'save cache'
```

or

```
import atexit
def save_cache():
    print 'save cache'
atexit.register(save_cache)
```

Answer (score 7):

[Yes, there is](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html):

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def writecache():
    # etc
```