# how to assign self to another instance of itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a class:

```
import copy
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, TestClass):
            self = value.deepcopy()
        else:
            self.data = value

    def deepcopy(self):
        return copy.deepcopy(self)
```

where I want to write the code such that if an instance of a class is initialized by another instance of the same class, it will make a `deepcopy` of the second class.

Now, if I try

```
In []: x = TestClass(3)
In []: x.data
Out[]: 3
```

But if I try

```
 In []: y = TestClass(x)
 Out[]: y.data
 ...
 AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Why didn't the `deepcopy` happen when the instance `x` was passed to `y` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216356/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-self-object-by-another-object-of-the-same-type-in-a-meth

Comment: so, essentially, I can't just assign self to another instance, but need to copy every attribute of the other instance to the current instance?

Comment: Or you can make a function that is not a constructor but returns a TestClass object.

Comment: When you do `self  = ...`, you are not replacing the current object with the copied object, but you are making the variable `self` refer the copied object.

Comment: In Python you'd normally say `y = x.copy()` rather than `y = TestClass(x)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution:

```
import copy
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, TestClass):
            self.__dict__ = copy.deepcopy(value.__dict__)
        else:
            self.data = value
```

This makes your example working. You want to do a 'copy constructor',
in Python objects have a `__dict__` attribute containing all
members so you can just copy the dictionary from the original object
and assign it to the new object `__dict__`.

Comment: this making a copy though, its not referencing the original object.

Comment: @JamieMarshall if it is to reference the original object, I would say a [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052736/python-proxy-class) is better, ie. an object that would transparently transfers to the original object. With some added members, maybe.