# Python proxy class

Tags: python, proxy-pattern

I'm trying to create a Proxy class to another class. I want this class to be passed into the proxy in its constructor and then for the proxy to dynamically create all the same methods of this class on itself.

This is what I hvae so far which is not working:

```
import inspect
from optparse import OptionParser

class MyClass:

    def func1(self):
        print 'MyClass.func1'


    def func2(self):
        print 'MyClass.func1'


class ProxyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        myClass = MyClass()
        members = inspect.getmembers(MyClass, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
        for member in members:
            funcName = member[0]
            def fn(self):
                print 'ProxyClass.' + funcName
                return myClass[funcName]()
            self.__dict__[funcName] = fn

proxyClass = ProxyClass()
proxyClass.func1()
proxyClass.func2()
```

I think it is the line `self.__dict__[funcName] = fn` that needs to be changed but am not sure what to?

I'm new to Python so if there is a completely different Pythonic way of doing this I would be happy to hear about that too.

Comment: You haven't said how it is "not working". Why do you think that dict assignment needs to change? Nevertheless, this is an odd approach. Is there any reason you don't want to simply delegate the calls by overriding `__getattr__`?

Comment: Current error is when I call proxyClass.func1() i says it needs to take 1 argument which suggests that the function hasn't been put on the instance properly

Comment: The whole premise of using a proxy pattern is to create a class that simplifies/limits ect. interaction with the original class, so just wondering why you are trying to just copy the members. And even if you need a 1:1 property and member access in proxy why not just pass your class to the proxy constructor and assign it to something like self.subject?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by assigning it to self.subject and how that will help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not explicitly copy the methods of the wrapped class. You can use the magic method `__getattr__` to control what happens when you call something on the proxy object, including decorating it as you like; `__getattr__` has to return a callable object, so you can make that callable do whatever you need to (in addition to calling the original method).

I have included an example below.

```
class A:
    def foo(self): return 42
    def bar(self, n): return n + 5
    def baz(self, m, n): return m ** n

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, proxied_object):
        self.__proxied = proxied_object

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        def wrapped_method(*args, **kwargs):
            print("The method {} is executing.".format(attr))
            result = getattr(self.__proxied, attr)(*args, **kwargs)
            print("The result was {}.".format(result))
            return result    
        return wrapped_method

proxy = Proxy(A())
proxy.foo()
proxy.bar(10)
proxy.baz(2, 10)
```

Comment: What if class A would have a "property" and "property.setter" decorators ? From my tests this does not work, since this wrapped method already works as a decorator I'm not sure if things somewhat clash.

Comment: @calexandru This is definitely not a complete and comprehensive solution, just something that can work for simple cases. If you need something with more power, check out a library like [wrapt](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt).