# Defer variable initialization until evaluation

Tags: python

I need a way to defer the initialization of a global variable until the firs access to it, the overall idea is expressed in the following Python pseudocode:

```py
FOO = bar

FOO.some_method_on_bar() # Init bar: bar = Bar(); bar.some_method_on_bar()
FOO.some_method_on_bar() # Use cached bar: bar.some_method_on_bar()
```

So far I'm thinking of somehow telling Python to call a special class method every time its instance is evaluated, but I can't seem to google it up:

```py
class LazyGetter:
    def __init__(self, get_value) -> None:
        self.get_value = get_value
    
    def __class__instance__access__(self):
        return self.get_value()

FOO = LazyGetter(get_value=lambda: Bar())
FOO # = LazyGetter.__class__instance__access__()
FOO.some_method_on_bar() # = LazyGetter.__class__instance__access__().some_method_on_bar()
```

So, basically I need to know if there's something equivalent to the madeup `__class__instance__access__` method.

Comment: One consideration would be that this will make the code that uses the global variable really hard to unit test

Answer (score 1):

If you have to defer initialization, you may be doing too much in the `__init__` method. But if you don't control that code, then you seem to be needing something like a proxy class, so you can do:

```
proxied_bar = Proxy(Bar)
...
proxied_bar.some_bar_method()  # this would initialize Bar, if it isn't yet initialized, and then call the some_bar_method
```

One way to do so, see: [Python proxy class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052736/python-proxy-class#46052931)

In that answer an instantiated object is proxied (rather than the class), so you have to make some modifications if you want to defer the `__init__` call.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.7, one can define a [module `__getattr__` method](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/) to programmatically provide "global" *attributes*. Earlier and more generally, [one can define a custom module type to provide such a method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access).

Assuming that `Bar()` is needed to initialise the global `FOO`, the following `__getattr__` *at module scope* can be used.

```py
# can type-annotate to "hint" that FOO will exist at some point
FOO: Bar

# called if module.<item> fails
def __getattr__(item: str):
    if item == "FOO":
       global FOO  # add FOO to global scope
       FOO = Bar()
       return FOO
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__!r} has no attribute {item!r}")
```

This makes `FOO` available programmatically when accessed *as an attribute*, i.e. as `module.FOO` or an import. It is only available in the global scope *after* the first such access.

If the access to `FOO` is expected to happen inside the module first, it is easier to provide a "getter" function instead.

```py
def get_FOO() -> Bar:
    global _FOO
    try:
        return _FOO
    except NameError:
        _FOO = Bar()
        return _FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider just having an actual global variable and accessing it with `global <variable>` but I can't say if that fits the use-case. It should work fine if you're just looking for some caching logic.

You might be able to do this with [metaclasses](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/) which is a way of modifying a class when it's instantiated. Whether this is useful depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the class code, you can use `__getattribute__` to delay initialization until the first time you access an attribute.

```
class Bar:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._args = args

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        args = super().__getattribute__('_args')
        if args is not None:
            # Initialize the object here.
            self.data = args[0]
            self.args = None
        return super().__getattribute__(name)

    def some_method_on_bar(self):
        return self.data
```