# tkinter - How to get text from entry created by class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning python and decided to create a calculator for uniform line movement with OOP and Tkinter. And because i needed a couple of entry boxes i created a class for it, but i am getting errors when triying to extract the text. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()  # Crea una ventana basica. SIEMPRE se debe utilizar
root.geometry('350x200')  # Setea las dimensiones de la ventana
root.title("Simple MRU Calculator.")


class labels:  # Crea labels de texto
    def __init__(self, texto, fuente, tamañoFuente, columna, rowa):
        self = Label(root, text=texto, font=(fuente, tamañoFuente)
                     ).grid(column=columna, row=rowa)


class entryBox:  # Crea entryboxes
    def __init__(self, largo, columna, rowa):
        self = Entry(root, width=largo)
        self.grid(column=columna, row=rowa)


entryBox_Distancia = entryBox(10, 1, 0)
entryBox_Velocidad = entryBox(10, 1, 1)
entryBox_TiempoF = entryBox(10, 1, 2)
entryBox_TiempoI = entryBox(10, 1, 3)


def calculando():
    entryBoxDT = entryBox_Distancia.get()
    print(entryBoxDT)


theLabel_Uno = labels('Distancia Inicial:', 'Arial', 11, 0, 0)
theLabel_Dos = labels('Velocidad', 'Arial', 11, 0, 1)
theLabel_Tres = labels('Tiempo Final', 'Arial', 11, 0, 2)
theLabel_Cuatro = labels('Tiempo Inicial', 'Arial', 11, 0, 3)

boton_Uno = Button(root, text='Calcular', command=calculando)
boton_Uno.grid(column=1, row=5)
theLabel_Cinco = labels('n', 'Arial', 11, 1, 4)


root.mainloop()  # Inicia la ventana
```

The error i am getting with it is this:
`AttributeError: 'entryBox' object has no attribute 'get'`

How do i get the text from each entryBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not inheriting from the entry widget. Simply putting `self = whatever` does not do anything. To make this work use this:

```py
class entryBox(Entry):  # inherit from the entry widget
    def __init__(self, largo, columna, rowa):
        super().__init__(width=largo)  # call the init method of the entry widget.
        self.grid(column=columna, row=rowa)
```

Now `entryBox` is an actual instance of the entry widget.

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp) is a good tutorial dealing with inheritance in python.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216356/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-self-object-by-another-object-of-the-same-type-in-a-meth) goes into more depth on why redefining self will not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now!!! I studied the info you gave me and could apply it other classes to fix problems that i could have in the future