# Why can't my version of a sorted list in Python add a second number?

Tags: python, class, instance

In the following code, I'm able to add the first number, but I can't add the second number. Inside the class, self correctly updates to [1, 3], but the instance stays at [1]. Why is that and how do I fix it?

```
from bisect import bisect
class SortedList(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self = []
    def add(self, x):
        index = bisect(self, x)
        if not self:
            self.append(x)
        else:
            self = self + [x] + self[index:] # after the second call self = [1, 3]
            pass
t = 1
for _ in range(t):
    n, a, b = 24, 3, 5
    if b == 1:
        print('yes')
    else:
        sl = SortedList() # sl = []
        st = set()
        sl.add(1) # sl = [1]
        st.add(1)
        i = 0
        while sl[i] < n: # when i == 1, there's an error because sl = [1]
            num1 = sl[i] * a # num1 = 3
            num2 = sl[i] + b
            if num1 > sl[i] and num1 not in st:
                sl.add(num1) # after this, sl = [1] still
                st.add(num1)
            if num2 > 1 and num2 not in st:
                sl.add(num2)
                st.add(num2)
            if n in st:
                break
            i += 1
        print('yes' if n in st else 'no')
```

Comment: Assigning to `self` in `__init__` does nothing useful.

Comment: You also can't enforce the invariant that your list remains sorted without overloading every method that lets you insert an element into the list (`append`, `extend`, __setitem__`, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify  `self`, when you assign the resulting list to  `self` you change its reference in the local context of the function. But the remote reference keep unchanged.
Better explained in [Is it safe to replace a self object by another object of the same type in a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216356/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-self-object-by-another-object-of-the-same-type-in-a-meth)

### By sub-classing `list`:

```py
import bisect

class SortedList(list):

    def append(self, x):
        if not self:
            super(SortedList, self).append(x)
        else:
            idx = bisect.bisect(self, x)
            self.insert(idx, x)
```

And then:

```py
>>> import random
>>> l = SortedList()
>>> for i in range(10):
...     l.append(random.randint(0, 100))
>>> print(l)
[5, 31, 50, 58, 69, 69, 70, 78, 85, 99]
```

In order to keep the list sorted you should also override some magic methods such `__add__`, `__iadd__` ...

### By wrapping `list`:

```py
class SortedList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def append(self, x):
        if not self:
            self._data = [x]
        else:
            idx = bisect.bisect(self, x)
            # Here you can change self._data
            # Even `insert` is better, because it don't need to copy the list
            # you can do
            self._data = self._data[:idx] + [x] + self._data[idx:]
```

But it's very partial, in order to have `SortedList` look like a list you have to implement the [sequence protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

Answer (score 1):

```
self = []
...
self = self + [x] + self[index:]
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. Whenever you write `a = ...` (without indexing on the left hand side, which is special) you don't actually change what `a` is. Instead, you just take whatever is on the right hand side and give it the *name* `a`, ignoring whatever `a` was before.

Example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a), id(b)
(140484089176136, 140484089176136)
>>> a.append(4) # Modification.
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a = a + [5] # Modification? No! We create a new object and label it 'a'.
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a), id(b)
(140484995173192, 140484089176136)
```

---

What you want is [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) and to use `list.insert`:

```
index = bisect_left(li, x)
li.insert(index, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone. I was able to get the code to work as expected by changing the class as follows:

```
class SortedList(list):
    def add(self, x):
        index = bisect(self, x)
        self.insert(index, x)
```