# What is the best pythonic way of wrapping an object?

Tags: python, design-patterns, wrapper

I would like to be able to wrap any object in Python. The following does not seem to be possible, would you know why?

```
class Wrapper:
    def wrap(self, obj):
        self = obj

a = list()
b = Wrapper().wrap(a)
# can't do b.append
```

Thank you!

Comment: Side note, if your on python 2.x its considered good practice to inherit from object

Comment: It's perfectly possible, it just doesn't do what you think it does. :) Python variables are not pointers, they are names. When you set `self = obj` you just say that the name "self" now points to the object which the name "obj" also points to. But names are local, or there could only be one self in the whole program, so it changes nothing. And that leads us to the next comment: When asking question, always explain *why* you are doing what you are doing. You don't seem to want to wrap the object, you seem to want to proxy it.

Comment: Why "wrap" an object?  Objects in Python never need wrappers, since they're always completely "compatible" with each other.  Can you provide some background on what you mean by "wrap"?  And why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with the getattr python magic :

```
class Wrapper:
    def wrap(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.obj, name)

a = list()
b = Wrapper()
b.wrap(a)

b.append(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for, that does the job you are looking to do, much more elegantly than you are trying to do it in, is:

[Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli)'s [Bunch Class](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/).

```
class Bunch:
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
    self.__dict__.update(kwds)

# that's it!  Now, you can create a Bunch
# whenever you want to group a few variables:

point = Bunch(datum=y, squared=y*y, coord=x)

# and of course you can read/write the named
# attributes you just created, add others, del
# some of them, etc, etc:
if point.squared > threshold:
    point.isok = 1
```

There are alternative implementations available in the linked recipe page.

Answer (score 0):

You're just referencing the variable self to be a certain object in wrap(). When wrap() ends, that variable is garbage collected.

You could simply save the object in a Wrapper attribute to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can also do what you want by overriding new:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __new__(cls, obj):
        return obj
t = Wrapper(list())
t.append(5)
```

Comment: This question might also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015592/why-is-self-in-python-objects-immutable

Comment: With this method, you've not really wrapped list, you've just made a no-op callable `Wrapper` that simply returns whatever it is passed. The `t` object _is_ a list object. (If `Wrapper` is passed a `Wrapper` subclass as argument (say you override `__new__` so it works properly again), then it will also call `__init__` on the object it is passed)