# Pyserial Error with __init__

Tags: pyserial

I'm trying to create a module that initializes a serial port connection using python:

```
import serial

class myserial:
   def __init__(self, port, baudrate)
       self = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)
```

When I run this in Python I get an AttributeError message stating that self does not have an attribute open.  Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with this code above?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do, assigning to `self`? See [Why is `self` in Python objects immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015592/why-is-self-in-python-objects-immutable) for an answer that discusses this.

Perhaps you want to elaborate more on what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the Serial object to a member of self, rather than directly to self

Something like this:

```
class myserial: 
        def __init__(self, port, baudrate):
                self.ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, you guys.  I realized that I was trying to set the Serial object directly to self just a few minutes ago. I just wanted to create a module that creates a serial port connection that I could reuse later.  Your answers are greatly appreciated.