# Loading serialised object from YAML and replacing current object with it

Tags: python, serialization

I have what I would have thought would be a fairly common problem, but I can't seem to find out how to do what I want.

I have a class in Python that has a number of instance variables which contain parameters for a model. I have added two methods to the class:

```
def save_params(self, filename):
    f = open(filename, "w")
    yaml.dump(self, f, default_flow_style=False)
    f.close()

def load_params(self, filename):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    obj = yaml.load(f)
    print obj.aero_soot
    self = copy.deepcopy(obj)
    f.close()
```

I want to use these to save the values of the attributes of this object to a YAML file, and then load them back from a YAML file.

`save_params` works fine, but `load_params` doesn't. It loads from the YAML file fine into `obj`, but the attributes in obj don't get set properly in the current instance of the object (`self`).

I'm probably doing something stupid here, but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your assignment to `self`, and it is explained very nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015592/why-is-self-in-python-objects-immutable). In short, within the function, `self` is a local name, and thus, binding it to a different value has no effect outside of the function.

To overcome this, you could probably use `self.__dict__ = obj.__dict__`. This would only work if you have not made any modifications to the `__dict__` of the current object.

I would however, recommend another apporach: Make the load and save functions either free functions or class-methods that return objects:

```
@classmethod
def save_params(cls, obj, filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        yaml.dump(obj, f, default_flow_style=False)

@classmethod   
def load_params(cls, obj, filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        obj = yaml.load(f)
        print obj.aero_soot
        return obj
```

Comment: Thank you - that makes sense.
Is there another way to do what I'm trying to do? (That is, create simple methods to save and restore the attributes of this object)

Comment: I think you mean `__dict__` rather than `__dir__`.

Comment: @Daniel: Indeed I do. Thanks and fixed!