# How can I optionally populate instance of an object from pickle file?

Tags: python, oop, pickle

Full code here: [link](http://bpaste.net/show/489218/)

Relevant code is:

`class Session():
    ...
    def load(self, create_date=None):
        if create_date:
            self = pickle.load(open(file_path(create_date), 'rb'))
        else:
            self = pickle.load(open(file_path(), 'rb'))`

I have defined a simple class "Session"
(It's a container for everything else my app will do).

I have a method for creating a fresh session, and saving it to a pickle.
I intend to have one Session = one Day.

So if the user re-opens the app on a particular day, it checks for an existing session and reloads it from the pickle.

My current code throws an error:
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'create_date'

I believe the line that isn't working properly is 44:
self = pickle.load(open(file_path(), 'rb'))

But I have a working variation on Line 12. (Not ideal, outside the class)

How can I load this existing pickle data and populate it into the "active_session" instance?

Comment: Including the *relevant* code in your question is **much** preferred.

Comment: as well as the full traceback ... not just the error message

Comment: I realise maybe I was asking the wrong question.
I believe this may be my answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015592/why-is-self-in-python-objects-immutable)
i.e. self is immutable