# self-assign a dict-comprehension to a class from dict

Tags: python, class, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm creating a child class from a dict object

```
class FeatureVector(dict):

    def __init__(self, init_val=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_val = init_val
```

Within this class I tried to self-assign a function with a dictionary-comprehension like this simplified example:

```
    def load_fv(self, fvlist):
        self = {k:float(val) for k, val in fvlist}
```

In this example the fvlist is built up like:

```
fvlist = [["example", 1], ["feature", 2], ["vector", 3], ["list", 4]]
```

This load_fv method doesn't work. The dict remains empty: `{}`

After some search I found this is because `self` is immutable, as explained here: [Why is `self` in Python objects immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015592/why-is-self-in-python-objects-immutable)

So perhaps I'm just trying to do something that I shouldn't. Off course there is the possibility to create a function that does the dict-comprehension using a for loop:

```
    def load_fv(self, fvlist):
        self.clear()
        for x, y in fvlist:
            self[x] = y
```

Still I can imagine cases where 'self-assigning' a dictionary to a dict-child class might be more efficient in case the dictionary is allready available, or when I want to initialize the dict-like-object with a dictionary.

In that case I could do something like:

```
    def __init__(self, init_dict, init_val=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_val = init_val
        self.load_fv(fvlist)

    def load_fv(self, fvlist):
        self.clear()
        if isinstance(fvlist, dict) or isinstance(fvlist, FeatureVector):
            fvlist = [[key, val] for key, val in fvdict.items()]
        for x, y in fvlist:
            self[x] = y
```

Still this doesn't really feel elegant and consice. Is there a better one-line / less verbose kind of way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
def __init__(self, init_dict, init_val=0):
    super().__init__()
    self.init_val = init_val
    self.update(init_dict)
    # Here init_dict is a dictionary or a dictionary like object
```

The `update` method adds the dictionary provided to itself.