# python - Can you replace an object completely by internal method?

Tags: python, object, methods, replace, internal

We are struggling with the following problem in python 3: we have defined a class, which inherits from `list`. We want to incorporate a method by which it can update itself to a new instance of this class.

Some very simple code to illustrate what we mean:

```
class test(list):
    def update(self):
        self = test(['a','b','c','d'])

x = test([1,2,3])
x.update()
print(x)
```

This code returns the original list `[1,2,3]`, which shows that the object x indeed hasn't been updated. Is there a way to let an object update itself completely? We need this to work for lists of different lengths.

Comment: `self` is just another reference to the instance. Assigning something different to that name won't change the instance, though.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the `test` instance with another `test` instance, or replace the *contents* of the `test` instance with `['a','b','c','d']`?

Comment: Check out the following threads:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015592/why-is-self-in-python-objects-immutable
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216356/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-self-object-by-another-object-of-the-same-type-in-a-meth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is *just another variable*. Method objects cause the current instance to be assigned to that name (just like other values are assigned to other function parameters), but like other names, assigning to them will *only change what object the name refers to*. Other names that reference the same object, like `x`, *do not change along*.

That's because names in Python code are [just like tags](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), and `self = <something else>` is like taking the tag of the old instance and putting it on another object. Any *other* tags still attached to the old object are not moved! Because `x` still references the old instance, it is not going to see that you put the `self` tag on another object.

Either your `update()` method needs to *return* the new object (so that the caller can update their reference to point to the new object), or change the list in-place (at which point *all references to the object* will see the same change.

Returning the object means the caller is responsible for doing something with the return value:

```
class test(list):
    def update(self):
        return test(['a','b','c','d'])

x = test([1,2,3])
x = x.update()  # re-bind `x` to point to the new object.
print(x)
```

Or you can assign to indices of the list itself; this changes what the *contents of the list* point to. You can use `self` just like any other reference, so `x[0] = 5` would change index 0, so would `self[0] = 5`. And if you assign to a *slice* you can change multiple indices at once. The *identity slice*, `[:]`, lets you change *all* indices at once, and you can assign more or fewer values to grow or shrink a list. Assigning to `self[:]` changes all indices, and lets you change all indices to point to any number of different values.

So:

```
class test(list):
    def update(self):
        self[:] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']


x = test([1,2,3])
x.update()
print(x)  # The x reference to the same list will see the change too
```

The above replaces all indices with the values in the other list. All references to the instance will see the change; both as `self` and `x`, and any other such references.

Demo of what this means:

```
>>> class test(list):
...     def update(self):
...         self[:] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
...
>>> x = test([1, 2, 3])
>>> y = x   # another reference to the same object
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x.update()  # update the list in-place
>>> x   # visible here
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> y   # and here!
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```