# How to make sure a subclass has the same initialiser as the baseclass?

Tags: python, oop, subclassing, default-constructor

Basically, I am trying to define a subclass of string which conforms with the [RFC UUID scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc4122/). An object of this class can only exist if it conforms to the 8-4-4-4-12 hex string, else does not. So I need to check it during initialisation, but not sure how to account for all possible initialisation arguments of `str`.

This is how my code looks like:

```
import uuid

class UniversalID(str):
    def __init__(self, val:str):
        super().__init__()
        try:
            uuid.UUID(hex=val)
            self=val
        except ValueError as inv_str:
            logging.error(msg=f'Invalid id queried {val}')
            raise inv_str

sample= uuid.uuid1().hex
isinstance(UniversalID(sample), str) # Shows true, as expected
```

But not sure if this is the right approach, as there may be other arguments of `str` initialiser that I am not taking care of.

The question can be generalised to, if I want to modify the `__init__` method with some validation check in the subclass, do I need to have total access to the initialiser in the base class, to make sure it accepts the same arguments and processes the same way? Worse still, do I have to, like, copy paste the code?

Comment: You do not need to worry about other initializers. You define the one initializer that you want to support. Other initilizers of the super class do not matter.

Comment: In Python the constructor is the `__new__()` method, and `__init__()` is an initializer method. Strings are an immutable type in Python, and the value of  immutable types are set in their `__new__()` method, not `__init__()` — so that is where you should put the validation code. Calling `super.__new__(*args)` in that method will insure the internals of the baseclass are set up properly — so after doing that you can refer to `self` like any other `str` value.

Comment: @martineau any reference code snippet available anywhere on the net or for example, an open source github repo?

Comment: I doubt inheritance is what you should use here. What `str` methods do you think are applicable to UUIDs? I would use composition: have the string be an *attribute* of `UniversalID`, and only define methods that make sense for UUIDs.

Comment: I just ran across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015602/355230) from a very authoritative source that the explains the differences between `__new__()` and `__init__()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment you have to set the value of immutable types, like strings, in their `__new__()` method. I couldn't find a canonical source or example for you — I know about it from some books I read long ago, so decided just to make up one for you (based on your code):

```
import logging
import uuid


class UniversalID(str):
    # You don't really need to define this, because it's what would happen anyway.
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            uuid.UUID(hex=self)
        except ValueError as inv_str:
            logging.error(msg=f'Invalid id queried {self}')
            raise inv_str


if __name__ == '__main__':

    sample1 = uuid.uuid1().hex
    try:
        isinstance(UniversalID(sample1), str)
    except ValueError as exc:
        print(f'ERROR: {exc} {sample1=!r}')
    else:
        print(f'{sample1=!r} is a valid hex uuid.')

    print()
    sample2 = 'not a hex uuid'
    try:
        isinstance(UniversalID(sample2), str)
    except ValueError as exc:
        print(f'ERROR: {exc} {sample2=!r}')
    else:
        print(f'{sample2=!r} is a valid hex uuid.')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete answer, but I am curious, what's the functional difference between my and your implementations? Is there an interface of your ```UniversalID``` class that behaves differently than as defined in my code?

Comment: One difference is that the `self=val` in your code isn't doing what you think, it's only changing what the local variable named `self` in the method refers to — it's not assigning a value to the current `UniversalID` instance. It can't because strings are immutable. You don't notice that it's not working because it's trying to assign a same value the instance already has (given to it in `__new__()`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create an instance that inherits from `uuid.UUID` and make the checks you want to the argument passed into your own constructor before you pass it to the super.