# Class inheritance - how to modify a pandas DataFrame in a method

Tags: pandas, dataframe, inheritance

The class myDataFrame inherits a pandas DataFrame. When I make modifications to the DataFrame using "self =", the operation completes successfully but in fact the DataFrame object is not modified. Why is this the case and what is the correct way to modify the DataFrame?

```
import pandas
class myDataFrame(pandas.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, adict):
        super().__init__(adict)

    def df_reorder_columns(self):
        self = self[["Name", "Number"]] # this assignment doesn't work
        
my_data = {'Number': [1, 2],
           'Name': ['Adam', 'Abel']}

test_myDataFrame = myDataFrame(my_data)
print(test_myDataFrame)
test_myDataFrame.df_reorder_columns()
print(test_myDataFrame)
```

```
   Number  Name
0       1  Adam
1       2  Abel
   Number  Name
0       1  Adam
1       2  Abel
```

Comment: I think the code should work with 'columns' attribute of the DataFrame in order to change it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is `self` in Python objects immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015592/why-is-self-in-python-objects-immutable)

Comment: TLDR of that; You should `return self[['Name', 'Number']]` and do `df = df.df_reorder_columns()` rather than trying to modify objects in-place. In-place methods tend to be frowned upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally... I think this makes more sense:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

class myDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def reorder_columns(self):
        self.__init__(self[['Name', 'Number']])


my_data = {'Number': [1, 2],
           'Name': ['Adam', 'Abel']}

df = myDataFrame(my_data)
print(df)

df = df.reorder_columns()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Number  Name
0       1  Adam
1       2  Abel

   Name  Number
0  Adam       1
1  Abel       2
```

---

But even better would be:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

class myDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def reorder_columns(self):
        return self[['Name', 'Number']]

my_data = {'Number': [1, 2],
           'Name': ['Adam', 'Abel']}

df = myDataFrame(my_data)
print(df)

df = df.reorder_columns()
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the dataframe object should be reinitilized with a desired order of columns

```
import pandas as pd     

class myDataFrame(pandas.DataFrame):

    def __init__(self, adict):
        super().__init__(adict)

    def df_reorder_columns(self):
        self.__init__({"Name": self.Name, "Number": self.Number})

my_data = {'Number': [1, 2],
           'Name': ['Adam', 'Abel']}

test_myDataFrame = myDataFrame(my_data)
print(test_myDataFrame)
test_myDataFrame.df_reorder_columns()
print(test_myDataFrame)
```

Comment: Sorry, I got you wrong though:) Going to update ASAP.