# How to wrapper built-in list in python?

Tags: python, wrapper

I want to define a class `ListWrapper` that has all list behaviors and also has a `filter` method.
It should work like this:

```py
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ls = ListWrapper(ls)
ls.filter(lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else False)
print(ls)
# out: [2, 4]
```

what should I do?

---

This is my attempt that failed

```py
class ListWrapper(list):
    def filter(self, func):
        filtered_list = list(filter(func, self))
        self = ListWrapper(filtered_list)
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ls = ListWrapper(ls)
ls.filter(lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else False)
print(ls)
# out: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your implementation work, you can modify the original ListWrapper object in place by removing all its elements and appending the filtered elements using the `clear()` and `extend()` methods.
Here's an updated implementation that should work as expected:

```
 class ListWrapper(list):
    def filter(self, func):
        filtered_list = list(filter(func, self))
        self.clear()
        self.extend(filtered_list)
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ls = ListWrapper(ls)
ls.filter(lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else False)
print(ls)
# out: [2, 4]
```

Comment: You could be much more concise using slice assignment: `self[:] = filter(func, self)`

Comment: @user2390182 - I just updated the code's provided by zhixin to make it easier for him/her.

Comment: Even there, the cleanest would be just replacing their last line with: `self[:] = filtered_list`

Comment: @dostogircse171 - Thanks. I understand your code. May I ask you that why my code doesn't work?

Comment: @user2390182 - Thanks. Could I think of `self[:]` herein as something like `list.__data__`? By the way, why my code didn't work?

Comment: `self[:] = ...` is equivalent to `self.__setitem__(slice(None), filtered_list)`. It mutates the list currently bound to `self`, rather than just making the name `self` refer to a different list.

Comment: I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015592/why-is-self-in-python-objects-immutable) helpful. `self` is a local variable refering to the object itself, it is a mutable type. 'self = filtered_list` leads to bonding a new local variable to the local varible. But 'self[:] = filtered_list` leads to altering the list variable it refers to.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the ListWrapper object in place, and not just substitute it with a new ListWrapper, otherwise the original list remains the same.

```py
class ListWrapper(list):
    def filter(self, func):
        filtered_list = list(filter(func, self))
        self.clear()
        self.extend(filtered_list)
```

This then should execute the way you want:

```py
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ls = ListWrapper(ls)
ls.filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
print(ls) #prints [2,4]
```

Note that

```py
lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else False
```

can be better re-written as

```py
lambda x: x % 2 == 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand your code. May I ask you that why my code doesn't work?

Comment: `self` is just a local variable. Assigning a new value to the name does not affect the list originally bound to that name.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call `list` on the `filter` object. `self.extend` accepts any iterable argument, not just lists.